# update function is not working

Tags: laravel

I am trying to update my database for a user by this code , but it is not working . there is no change by the way!

```
 public function update( Request $request)
    {

        $request->user()->tasks()->where('id', '=', $request->id)->update([
            'name' => $request->title,
            'body' => $request->body,
        ]);


        return redirect('/request');

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try code and update database:

App\User::find($request->id)->tasks()->update([
    'name' => $request->title,
    'body' => $request->body
]);


return redirect('/request');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the id of the task, make it easy on yourself.

```
Task::find($request->id)->update([
    'name' => $request->title,
    'body' => $request->body
]);
```